# Digamma equation for fitting

Tags: digamma-function

I have a digamma equation: ln(1/t) = psi(1/2 + h/2*t) - psi(1/2). I would like to reorganize this equation to apply for experimental data fitting (h and t are data points, t is input and h is output). anyone can help to convert this equation to f(x) = a*x + b. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: The question is not clear; Could you reawrite *psi(1/2 + h/2t)* with parentheses ?

Comment: thank you the equation is ln(1/t) = psi ((1/2)+(h/2*t))-psi(1/2).